# Issues with Eclipse constantly performing clean/build

Tags: java, eclipse, building

We recently started using Eclipse to develop our java application and have been running into some issues.  It should be known that we do not use any version tracker, or build software which probably is not best practice, although I was hoping to find an alternative solution to our problem.  We have up to 4-5 developers who could be editing a particular project at one time.  Throughout our work days, we constantly run into Eclipse wanting to clean/build the project as certain files are edited.  We were previously developing using TextPad and compiling at the command line, and would ideally like to use Eclipse in a similar fashion to make coding easier.  Is there anyway to setup Eclipse to do what we're trying to do, or will we need to start using some kind of version tracker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use version control, for many reasons, not just this issue.

If you're all editing the code in the same location on a share, that'd cause this issue.  You can avoid that by everyone having a local copy, which would require version control of some kind.

Comment: +1 on using version control.  Eclipse and its workspace concept were designed to edit local copies of files that came from a version control system.

Answer (score 2):

De select Project -> Build Automatically in your eclipse. You need to manually build your project when you want to. Think this is what you are expecting